# NodeJS/React: Taking a picture, then sending it to mongoDB for storage and later display

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I've been working on a small twitter-like website to teach myself React. It's going fairly well, and i want to allow users to take photos and attach it to their posts. I found a library called React-Camera that seems to do what i want it do to - it brings up the camera and manages to save something.

I say something because i am very confused about what to actually -do- with what i save. This is the client-side code for the image capturing, which i basically just copied from the documentation:

```
 takePicture() {
    try {
        this.camera.capture()
        .then(blob => {
          this.setState({
            show_camera: "none",
            image: URL.createObjectURL(blob)
          })
          console.log(this.state);
          this.img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          this.img.onload = () => { URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src); }

            var details = {
            'img': this.img.src,
            };

            var formBody = [];
            for (var property in details) {
              var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
              var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
              formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
            }
            formBody = formBody.join("&");
                fetch('/newimage', {
                    method: 'post',
                    headers: {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'},
                    body: formBody
                  });
                  console.log("Reqd post")
```

But what am i actually saving here? For testing i tried adding an image to the site and setting src={this.state.img} but that doesn't work. I can store this blob (which looks like, for example,  *blob:http://localhost:4000/dacf7a61-f8a7-484f-adf3-d28d369ae8db*)
or the image itself into my DB, but again the problem is im not sure what the correct way to go about this is.

Basically, what i want to do is this:
1. Grab a picture using React-Camera
2. Send this in a post to /newimage
3. The image will then - in some form - be stored in the database
4. Later, a client may request an image that will be part of a post (ie. a tweet can have an image). This will then display the image on the website.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i feel i am just getting more confused the more libraries i look at!

Answer (score 4):

From your question i came to know that you are storing image in DB itself.

If my understanding is correct then you are attempting a `bad approcah`. 
For this

1. you need to store images in project directory using your node application.
2. need to store path of images in DB.
3. using these path you can fetch the images and can display on webpage.

for uploading image using `nodejs` you can use `Multer` package.

Comment: Hi! What is the best way to send the actual photo to the backend? As currently it's being given to me as a Blob - do i need to convert it somehow?

Comment: no, you can directly store as jpeg/jpg/png format. buy your contenttype should be `multipart/form-data`. check this link https://scotch.io/tutorials/express-file-uploads-with-multer